# How can i design a beautiful UI for my android application

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

i'm beginner in android eclipse,How can design a beautiful UI for my application eclipse?
my android ver 2.2.
can I use a program to create UI xml and insert into my xml file?

Comment: What about using a little imagination?

Comment: what is this?little imagination?

Comment: How do you call it? fantasy? have you really no fantasy? then programming is really far from your attitudes...

Comment: By asking questions like this (too vague, general or resource seeking), you will either get not very serious, or opinionated answers on SO. I'd recommend googling it, there are tones and tones and tones of materials on designing the UI for Android apps.

Comment: your question is too broad and open-ended. Designing user interface in mobile applications is very general, and mostly depends on the final product requirements. Try to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Android Design](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html).  Seems like a legit place to start with a question this broad.